what is the better way to add conditional routing in rails
I have to change the route in a way that I need to have the original route as well as change the path of the route in a env is available.
this is how I am thinking of doing
    
    custom_org = ENV['CUSTOM_ORG']&.downcase
    custom_org_pronoun = custom_org.pluralize
    if ! custom_org_pronoun.nil? && custom_org_pronoun.present?
      resources :organizations, only: %i[], path: custom_org_pronoun do
        resources :merge_users, only: %i[new create], path: '/merge-users'
      end
    end
    resources :organizations, only: %i[], path: plural_custom_org_pronoun do
      resources :merge_users, only: %i[new create], path: '/merge-users'
    end


the desired output I want is that the \organizations and (lets say custom_org = home)  \homes both should work at the same time

Not an answer but an observation, on line 1 you are using safe navigation (&.); however on line 2 you are calling pluralize. If ENV['CUSTOM_ORG'] results in nil which is a suggested possibility given the safe nav, line 2 will raise a NoMethodError. Additionally plural_custom_org_pronoun is undefined. Also if you could provide a basic example of the desired outcome that might be beneficial.

In reading your update your current proposed solution results in /homes/:organization_id/merge-users but it seems like you want /homes/merge-users in which case you would probably want to go with scope '/:org', constraints: {org: Regexp.union([custom_org_pronoun,plural_custom_org_pronoun].compact)} this should result in /home/merge-users and /homes/merge-users as accessible routes represented as '/:org/merge-users' but I would still need more clarity before calling this an "answer".

Can you give us a better example of how this is intended to work? For example If ENV['CUSTOM_ORG'] ="foo" I expect the routes ... to be generated.
